# Pure Perl RPM Version checker

Tags: scripting, rpm, perl, versioning

I have a machine located in a secure environment that does not have access to the internet.  I has a base load of CentOS with a handful of additional RPMs.  This includes a basic install of PERL with no additional modules.  Nor does it have GCC installed so I can't install new modules manually nor use CPAN to install them.  Therefore, I need a pure Perl solution.

I've been asked to create a Perl script that will validate that the machine has a specific list of RPMs installed and that they're a specific version or newer.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# This is the list of RPMs to look for on the machine.
my @RPMs = ("bwm-ng",
        "celt051",
        "device-mapper-multipath",
        "device-mapper-multipath-libs",
        "dhcp",
        "dhcp-common",
        "ebtables",
        "freeglut",
        "glusterfs-api",
        "glusterfs-libs",
        "gnutls-utils",
        "gpm",
        "hmaccalc",
        "iftop",
        "iperf",
        "ipsec-tools",
        "iptraf",
        "iscsi-initiator-utils",
        "libsysfs",
        "lm_sensors",
        "lm_sensors-libs",
        "log4cpp",
        "lrzsz",
        "lzop",
        "mcsctrans",
        "minicom",
        "nc",
        "netcf-libs",
        "net-snmp",
        "net-snmp-libs",
        "net-snmp-utils",
        "omping",
        "perl-AppConfig",
        "perl-Pod-POM",
        "perl-Template-Toolkit",
        "pimd",
        "python-lxml",
        "quagga",
        "radvd",
        "smcroute",
        "usbredir",
        "yajl");

# These are the RPM versions that they should be equal to or newer than.
my @RPMVersions = ("bwm-ng-0.6-6.el6.2.x86_64",
        "celt051-0.5.1.3-0.el6.x86_64",
        "device-mapper-multipath-0.4.9-87.el6.x86_64",
        "device-mapper-multipath-libs-0.4.9-87.el6.x86_64",
        "dhcp-4.1.1-49.P1.el6.centos.x86_64",
        "dhcp-common-4.1.1-49.P1.el6.centos.x86_64",
        "ebtables-2.0.9-6.el6.x86_64",
        "freeglut-2.6.0-1.el6.x86_64",
        "glusterfs-api-3.4.0.57rhs-1.el6_5.x86_64",
        "glusterfs-libs-3.4.0.57rhs-1.el6_5.x86_64",
        "gnutls-utils-2.8.5-18.el6.x86_64",
        "gpm-1.20.6-12.el6.x86_64",
        "hmaccalc-0.9.12-2.el6.x86_64",
        "iftop-1.0-0.7.pre4.el6.x86_64",
        "iperf-2.0.5-11.el6.x86_64",
        "ipsec-tools-0.8.0-25.3.x86_64",
        "iptraf-3.0.1-14.el6.x86_64",
        "iscsi-initiator-utils-6.2.0.873-14.el6.x86_64",
        "libsysfs-2.1.0-7.el6.x86_64",
        "lm_sensors-3.1.1-17.el6.x86_64",
        "lm_sensors-libs-3.1.1-17.el6.x86_64",
        "log4cpp-1.0-13.el6_5.1.x86_64",
        "lrzsz-0.12.20-27.1.el6.x86_64",
        "lzop-1.02-0.9.rc1.el6.x86_64",
        "mcsctrans-0.3.1-4.el6.x86_64",
        "minicom-2.3-6.1.el6.x86_64",
        "nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64",
        "netcf-libs-0.2.4-3.el6.x86_64",
        "net-snmp-5.5-54.el6.x86_64",
        "net-snmp-libs-5.5-54.el6.x86_64",
        "net-snmp-utils-5.5-54.el6.x86_64",
        "omping-0.0.4-1.el6.x86_64",
        "perl-AppConfig-1.66-6.el6.x86_64",
        "perl-Pod-POM-0.25-2.el6.x86_64",
        "perl-Template-Toolkit-2.22-5.el6.x86_64",
        "pimd-2.3.0-1.x86_64",
        "python-lxml-2.2.3-1.1.el6.x86_64",
        "quagga-0.99.23.1-2014082501.x86_64",
        "radvd-1.6-1.el6.x86_64",
        "smcroute-2.0.0-0.x86_64",
        "usbredir-0.5.1-2.el6.x86_64",
        "yajl-1.0.7-3.el6.x86_64");

my $RPMname; #This reprepsents an individual RPM name within the @RPMs array.

foreach $RPMname (@RPMs){ # Loop through the @RPMs array and query the RPM database for each RPM.
    my $cmd = "rpm -qa | grep " . $RPMname;

    my @cmdResults = `$cmd`;

    if (! @cmdResults){
        print "\tMissing RPM: " . $RPMname . "\n\n"; # If the RPM isn't installed; inform the user.
    } else {
        foreach(@cmdResults){
            print "\t" . $_ . "\n"; # Print the version of the RPM that's currently installed.

            # Compare the RPM version that's installed with the corresponding version that should be installed
            # as listed in the @RPMVersions array.
            # write some magic here. <------

        }
    }
}

exit(0);
```

I've found what appears to be a possible solution but I can't seem to figure out how to adjust the code of fit my scenario.

see here: http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node=240384

I can't use RPM::VersionSort or several of the other RPM related modules because of the restrictions that I mentioned above.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ServerFault is not a script writing service.

Comment: Perl would certainly work, but have you considered Python? Python RPM bindings will be installed for yum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints

You do't need grep e.g.

```
rpm -q radvd
radvd-1.9.2-9.el7.x86_64
echo $?
0
```

If a package is missing $? is 1

```
rpm -q nc 
package nc is not installed
echo $?
1
```

You can get the version of an installed rpm package using --queryformat

```
rpm -q radvd --queryformat "%{VERSION}\n"
1.9.2
```

There is much more you can do with just rpm - [have a look at the rpm.org site](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html).

You may even be able to get away without using perl so take a look at Dennis's answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/how-compare-two-strings-in-dot-separated-version-format-in-bash).

Comment: I want to mark this post as the answer since I used some of it for my solution in the end.  But I don't know if I should since it doesn't exactly answer the original question.

Comment: It does because it points you in the right direction and we're not a script writing service anyway.

Comment: I never expected anyone to write the script for me.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer my original question I'd like to provide what I ended up with.  I've been able to convince those in power to allow me to install the RPM::VersionSort Perl module.  So this isn't a Pure Perl solution as I was hoping to find.

Here's what I'm using now for anyone who's interested:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use RPM::VersionSort;

my $cmd;
my $cmdResults;
my %installedRPMs; #This will hold a list of all the RPMs from the baseRPMs list that ARE currently installed on the machine.
my @missingRPMs; #This will hold a list of all the RPMs from the baseRPMs list that ARE NOT installed on the system.
my %baseRPMs; #This is the list of RPMs that should be installed on the system and their corresponding version numbers.

%baseRPMs = ("bwm-ng" => "0.6-6.el6.2",
        "celt051" => "0.5.1.3-0.el6",
        "device-mapper-multipath" => "0.4.9-87.el6",
        "device-mapper-multipath-libs" => "0.4.9-87.el6",
        "dhcp" => "4.1.1-49.P1.el6.centos",
        "dhcp-common" => "4.1.1-49.P1.el6.centos", 
        "ebtables" => "2.0.9-6.el6",
        "freeglut" => "2.6.0-1.el6",
        "glusterfs-api" => "3.4.0.57rhs-1.el6_5",
        "glusterfs-libs" => "3.4.0.57rhs-1.el6_5",
        "gnutls-utils" => "3.8.5-18.el6",
        "gpm" => "1.20.6-12.el6",
        "hmaccalc" => "0.9.12-2.el6",
        "iftop" => "1.0-0.7.pre4.el6",
        "iperf" => "2.0.5-11.el6",
        "ipsec-tools" => "0.8.0-25.3",
        "iptraf" => "3.0.1-14.el6",
        "iscsi-initiator-utils" => "6.2.0.873-14.el6",
        "libsysfs" => "2.1.0-7.el6",
        "lm_sensors" => "3.1.1-17.el6",
        "lm_sensors-libs" => "3.1.1-17.el6",
        "log4cpp" => "1.0-13.el6_5.1",
        "lrzsz" => "0.12.20-27.1.el6",
        "lzop" => "1.02-0.9.rc1.el6",
        "mcsctrans" => "0.3.1-4.el6",
        "minicom" => "2.3-6.1.el6",
        "nc" => "1.84-24.el6",
        "netcf-libs" => "0.2.4-3.el6",
        "net-snmp" => "5.5-54.el6",
        "net-snmp-libs" => "5.5-54.el6",
        "net-snmp-utils" => "5.5-54.el6",
        "omping" => "0.0.4-1.el6",
        "perl-AppConfig" => "1.66-6.el6",
        "perl-Pod-POM" => "0.25-2.el6",
        "perl-Template-Toolkit" => "2.22-5.el6",
        "pimd" => "2.3.0-1",
        "python-lxml" => "2.2.3-1.1.el6",
        "quagga" => "0.99.23.1-2014082501",
        "radvd" => "1.6-1.el6",
        "smcroute" => "2.0.0-0",
        "usbredir" => "0.5.1-2.el6",
        "yajl" => "1.0.7-3.el6",
    );

print "The following RPMs and version numbers will be checked against this system:\n";
foreach(keys %baseRPMs){
    print "\t" . $_ . ": " . %baseRPMs($_) . "\n";
}

print "Press any key to continue.";
<STDIN>;

#Loop through the %baseRPMs list and build both the %installedRPMs list as well as the @missingRPMs list.
for my $pkg (keys %baseRPMs){
    $cmd = "rpm -q " . $pkg . " --queryformat \"%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\"";
    $cmdResults = `$cmd`;
    if ($cmdResults =~ /not installed/) {
        push @missingRPMs, $pkg;
    } else {
        $installedRPMs{$pkg} = $cmdResults;
    }
}

#Loop through the %installedRPMs list and verify their version numbers against the %baseRPMs list.
foreach (keys %installedRPMs){
    if (exists $baseRPMs{$_}){
        print "Expected: " . $_ . ": " . $baseRPMs{$_} .  "\n";
        print "Installed: " . $_ . ": " . $installedRPMs{$_} .  "\n";
        if (rpmvercmp($installedRPMs{$_}, $baseRPMs{$_}) < 0 ) {
            print "RESULT: !!FAIL!! " . $_ . " version is OLDER than the specified version in the Functional Test Plan.\n";
        } else {
            print "RESULT: PASS. " . $_ . " version is equal to or newer than the specified version in the Functional Test Plan. \n";
        }
        print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    }
}

#Print the list of @missingRPMs.
if (@missingRPMs){
    print "The following RPMs are NOT installed as defined by the Functional Test Plan:\n";
    foreach(@missingRPMs){
        print "\t" . $_ . "\n";
    }
    print "\n*Any missing RPMs indicates the system is NOT built as defined by the Functional Test Plan.*\n";
}

print "\n";

exit(0)
```

;